# Scala Package Object Override issue: Value #:: is not a member of ...Stream[Int]

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala code:

```
object primes {
  def from(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n #:: from(n + 1)
}
```

and I am receiving the error: `Error:(8, 37) value #:: is not a member of ...Stream[Int]  .... def from(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n #:: from(n + 1)`

I am trying to implement the Stream cons operator [#::](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html##::[B%3E:A](hd:B):scala.collection.immutable.Stream[B]).  How can I fix this error?

Comment: This code works for me in `2.11.11`.  Are you sure you are using a `scala.collection.immutable.Stream` ?

Comment: I am using Scala version 2.12.1.

Comment: I also tried importing `scala.collection.immutable.Stream._`, but it said it was being unused in the file.

Comment: This is working for me in 12.2.1, you are not importing a Stream from somewhere else by accident are you?  Try this `def from(n: Int): scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = n #:: from(n + 1)`

Comment: It turns out I was importing an alternate version of a trait Stream from a different file in the package.  Once I commented out the package, it worked perfectly.  Thanks for the help @Tyler!

Comment: Ill put that down as an answer so that other people can find it more easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the correct `Stream`?  The one you should be using is `scala.collection.immutable.Stream`, try doing this to make sure there is no ambiguity:

```
object primes {
  def from(n: Int): scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = n #:: from(n + 1)
}
```

If that works, then you probably have an `import` statement elsewhere that is importing some other `Stream`.